# Wordpress special admin menu for a unique user

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have a custom menu in my wordpress back office created with this code in the functions.php file :

```
add_menu_page( 'Volunteers', 'Volunteers', 'edit_pages', 'volunteers.php', '', 'dashicons-groups', 23 );
```

I want to create a user who will access only this page in the back office. In other means, when connected, he only see in the left menu of the back office, the "Volunteers" menu.

How can I do that ?

PS: if it's possible, I want to make this possible without update the menu.php file in the directory wp-admin because this file is reinitialized with the wordpress updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this wordpress plugin first: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

;)
NC

Comment: Thanks, I would prefere an other way than use a plugin, but it's work, it's more important ;)